# INSERT INTO is not working foreign key php

Tags: php, insert, key

The check 'if' works but the values are not updating into the database. what is wrong?
I think is the code is right, it confirms the sucess from the insert. The foreign key is emp_id that references the primary key from a table called empresa (idempresa).

```
    // get post from other file
      @$pegar = $_POST['postempresa'];
      $q = " SELECT idempresa FROM empresa WHERE idempresa = $pegar " ;


      if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);




        // Grab the medida data from the POST


        $fk_empresa = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['chaveestrangeira']));


        $prato = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_prato']));
        $medida = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_medida']));
        $preco = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_preco']));
        $pessoas = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_pessoas']));
        $categoria = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_categoria']));
        $obs = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['f_obs']));
        $foto = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_FILES['f_foto']['name']));
        $foto_type = $_FILES['f_foto']['type'];
        $foto_size = $_FILES['f_foto']['size']; 




        if (!empty($prato) && !empty($medida) && !empty($preco) && !empty($pessoas) && !empty($categoria) ) {

          if ((($foto_type == 'image/gif') || ($foto_type == 'image/jpeg') || ($foto_type == 'image/pjpeg') || ($foto_type == 'image/png')) && ($foto_size > 0) && ($foto_size <= GW_MAXSIZECARD)) {
            if ($_FILES['f_foto']['error'] == 0) {
              // Move the file to the target upload folder
              $target = GW_UPCARD . $foto;
              if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['f_foto']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                // Write the data to the database


                $query = 

                "INSERT INTO cardapio SET

                 emp_id = '$q',
                 prato = '$prato',
                 medida = '$medida',
                 preco = '$preco',
                 pessoas = '$pessoas',
                 categoria = '$categoria',
                 obs = '$obs',
                 foto = '$foto'


                 ";

                mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

                echo mysql_error();

                // Confirm success with the user
                echo '<p>Cardapio enviado!</p>';
                echo '<p><strong>ID EMPRESA</strong> ' . $fk_empresa . '<br />';
                echo '<p><strong>prato:</strong> ' . $prato . '<br />';
                echo '<strong>Medida:</strong> ' . $medida . '<br />';
                echo '<strong>Preço:</strong> ' . $preco . '<br />';
                echo '<strong>Categoria:</strong> ' . $categoria . '<br />';
                echo '<strong>Obs:</strong> ' . $obs . '<br />';
                echo '<img src="' . GW_UPCARD . $foto . '" alt="Score image" /></p>';
                echo '<p><a href="index.php">Voltar para admin</a></p>';

                // Clear the medida data to clear the form
                $prato = "";
                $medida = ""; 
                $preco = "";
                $pessoas = "";
                $categoria = "";
                $obs = "";
                $foto = "";



                mysqli_close($dbc);

              }
              else {
                echo '<p class="error">Tivemos um erro no upload da imagem.</p>';
              }
            }
          }
          else {
            echo '<p class="error">A imagem precisa ter extensão GIF, JPEG, ou PNG e menor que ' . (GW_MAXSIZECARD / 1024) . ' KB.</p>';
          }

          // Try to delete the temporary screen shot image file
          @unlink($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
        }
        else {
          echo '<p class="error">Por favor, preencha todos os campos.</p>';
        }
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: sorry i'm a new developer, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

You are not executing query. Execute it like this

```
$rec    = " SELECT idempresa FROM empresa WHERE idempresa = $pegar " ;
$result =   mysqli_query($rec);
if($result){
    $row    =   myqsli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $q      =   $row['idempresa'];
}else{
    $q = '';
}
```

now the other thing is that your insert query is totally wrong. 
it does not use set keyword . Use it like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cardapio 
            (emp_id ,prato ,medida ,preco , pessoas , categoria , obs ,foto )
            VALUES
            ('$q','$prato','$medida','$preco','$pessoas','$pessoas','$categoria','$obs','$foto')";
mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in C:\wamp\www\mrdelivery\admin\insertcardapio.php on line 34 
I tried but the mysql function didn't work...

Comment: here is the database with the 2 tables

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cardapio` (
  `idcardapio` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `prato` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `medida` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preco` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pessoas` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoria` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obs` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcardapio`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emp_id` (`emp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=45 ;

Comment: this is coming because the row is not found so result is null which is being passed to mysql_fetch_assoc. Play with if condition

Comment: what is the type of idempresa. if it is varchar  use this `$rec    = " SELECT idempresa FROM empresa WHERE idempresa = '$pegar'" ;`. Enclose the variable in commas to work

Comment: ok, that problem is fixed, but I can't insert the values into the cardapio table... It's still not working... the code executes the query but in the db the values are not inserted...

Comment: I let the 'emp_id' without the foreign key and the php insert into is working well, but when i add a constraint foreign key to this field the db is not updated with the value....

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `empresa` (
  `idempresa` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomefantasia` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `razaosocial` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cnpj` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `cepemp` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `estadoemp` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `empcidade` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `ruaemp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bairroemp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `numeroemp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `compemp` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `categoriaemp` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `logomarca` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `telefoneum` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefonedois` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `emailum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emaildois` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idempresa`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

--
ALTER TABLE `cardapio`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cardapio_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`) REFERENCES `empresa` (`idempresa`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;